# Powershell DSC - Buffer is not supported. Check encoding and length of the buffer

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, dsc

On a Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual Machine, I am trying to run a Powershell DSC script:

Configuration Test 
{

```
    Node "localhost" 
    {    
        WindowsFeature WASDotNet3
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "WAS-NET-Environment"
        }    
    }
```

}

Test -OutputPath 'D:\PSMofFiles'
Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose -Path 'D:\PSMofFiles'

When I run this script, I get the following error:

```
Directory: D:\PSMofFiles
```

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         5/20/2014   8:55 AM       1218 localhost.mof
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespace
Name' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
**Buffer is not supported. Check encoding and length of the buffer**
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MiClientApiError_Failed
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

VERBOSE: Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
VERBOSE: Time taken for configuration job to complete is 0.19 seconds

PS C:\Windows\system32>

Would anyone know what is causing this?  Also, it doesn't matter what DSC script I run.  It can be any DSC script and I get the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing a patch on Windows Server 2012 R2 located here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40774
 to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with `rm C:\Windows\System32\Configuration\DSCEngineCache.mof`.

By manually inspecting these files (copy to the desktop if you want to use Explorer) I found that this mof file was all null characters. I don't know how that happened, but it could have something to do with "The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block" appearing in event log every few seconds.